# Best way to deserialize a .net core json request body with large values

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-core

I'm using .net core and I'm trying to deserialize a json request body with large values (possibly > 85K) while minimizing LOH accesses and garbage collection. My most current strategy is to use JsonDocument (as recommended by microsoft documentation) and pass around a JsonElement until the value is needed, where I call JsonElement.GetBytesFromBase64() and wrap with a MemoryStream, but, from what I can tell, this requires a heap allocation for the resulting byte array in some cases > 85K resulting in storing on the LOH. Is there a way to stream directly from the JsonElement to the MemoryStream, or to store the contents of the JsonElement in an array from the ArrayPool? I wish I could call JsonElement.GetBytesFromBase64(poolArray), or JsonElement.GetStream().

The request body looks like below:

```
[
  {
    "prop1": "shortVal",
    "prop2": "looooooooooong val.......",
    "prop3": "shortVal"
  },
  {
    "prop1": "shortVal",
    "prop2": "looooooooooong val.......",
    "prop3": "shortVal"
  }    
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the request body has only two element in the array. I think the best method is to get the prop2 to array list.and then cast the json to a list.
I mean you can get out the prop2 in to array list.

```
[
{
     "prop1":"shortVal",
     "prop3":"shortVal"
},
{
    "prop1": "shortVal",
    "prop3": "shortVal"
  } 
]
```

and the prop2 is in array or list.
when you need the property just get it from the list.